Quadratic formula proof geometric meaning
My proof of $x=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ is as follows:

find minimum using calculus $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$
notice that the distance from the minimum to each of the roots is the same
minimum is at the point ($\frac{-b}{2a}$,$\frac{-b^2}{4a}+c$)
substitute $(\frac{-b}{2a}+c)+\Delta{x}$ into $ax^2+bx+c=0$ to find the roots: (...)
$a(\frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\Delta{x}^2-\frac{b\Delta{x}}{a})+(\frac{-b^2}{2a}+b\Delta{x})+c=0$
the $b\Delta{x}$ cancels out and after some reordering we get the quadratic formula.

My question is the following: how can we know in advance that the $b\Delta{x}$ is going to cancel out? Otherwise you would just be left again with another quadratic equation of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$. I'm looking for some geometric intuition that explains why this happened and that it wasn't just luck.

The cancellation of $b\Delta x$ comes from the symmetry of the parabola. The linear term $bx$ corresponds to the slope of the tangent line at any point, and since the parabola is symmetric about the vertex, the slope contributions to the change in $y$-value from the roots cancel out on either side. In other words, the linear term $b\Delta x$ represents a shift that would affect one side of the parabola, but because we're working with both sides (symmetric distances) the contributions from $+\Delta x$ and $-\Delta x$ negate.
